# Windows 8, launch application on start up

Tags: windows-8, launch

Is there a way to launch a desktop application and skip the start screen at the same time when using Windows 8.  I tried making a new Scheduled Task but that only started the application in the desktop, but it did not skip the Metro screen.  I pinned the app on the Metro start screen. Is there a way to launch the tile?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot skip the start screen with windows 8, but windows 8.1 will enable this option.
To start a desktop application, you can put an link of the executable into this folder:
Press WIN+R on the keyboard
type: shell:startup and press enter.
Put the link into this folder
Done

Answer (score 0):

**To launch on desktop :**

Registry key : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Value : Shell

Put: explorer.exe/select,explorer.exe

*OR*

Sheduled task : launch %systemdrive%\Windows\explorer.exe ;)

**To launch your application**

Scheduled Task is a good solution ;)